# Decreasing EXE Size

Tags: c, space-efficiency, coding-efficiency

I wrote a TicTacToe program in C that reads 68.3 KB on my hard disk, and I was wondering if there are any sort of optimization techniques I could use to decrease the amount of bytes in my `.exe` file.

For instance, is there anything in my code that I could change to make the resulting executable "smaller"?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void drawBoard(int [3][3]);
bool boardFull(int [3][3]);
bool checkWin(int [3][3], int);

int main()
{
    int board[3][3];
    int marker, turn, row, column, i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            board[i][j] = -1;
    }

    printf("Player One is X\n");
    printf("Player Two is O\n");
    drawBoard(board);

    while(!boardFull(board))
    {
        if((turn % 2) == 0)
        {
            printf("Player One's turn.\n");
            marker = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Player Two's turn.\n");
            marker = 0;
        }

        printf("Which row? ");
        scanf("%i", &row);

        printf("Which column? ");
        scanf("%i", &column);

        if(board[row - 1][column - 1] != -1)
        {
            while(board[row - 1][column - 1] != -1)
            {
                printf("Space already taken. Try again.\n");

                printf("Which row? ");
                scanf("%i", &row);

                printf("Which column? ");
                scanf("%i", &column);

                printf("\n");
            }
        }
        board[row - 1][column - 1] = marker;

        drawBoard(board);

        if(checkWin(board, marker))
        {
            if(marker == 1)
                printf("Player One wins!!");
            else
                printf("Player Two wins!!");

            return 0;
        }

        turn++;
    }
    printf("Cat's game!\n");    

    return 0;
}

void drawBoard(int board[3][3])
{
    int i, j;

    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("  ");
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {   
            if(board[i][j] == 0)
                printf("O");
            else if(board[i][j] == 1)
                printf("X");
            else
                printf(" ");

            if(j == 2)
                continue;
            else
                printf(" | ");
        }
        if(i == 2)
            printf("\n\n");
        else
            printf("\n -----------\n");
    }
}

bool boardFull(int board[3][3])
{
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if(board[i][j] == -1)
                return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

bool checkWin(int board[3][3], int w)
{
    return
        board[0][0] == w && board[1][1] == w && board[2][2] == w
        || board[0][2] == w && board[1][1] == w && board[2][1] == w
        || board[0][0] == w && board[1][0] == w && board[2][0] == w
        || board[0][1] == w && board[1][1] == w && board[2][1] == w
        || board[0][2] == w && board[1][2] == w && board[2][2] == w
        || board[0][0] == w && board[0][1] == w && board[2][2] == w
        || board[1][0] == w && board[1][1] == w && board[2][2] == w
        || board[2][0] == w && board[2][1] == w && board[2][2] == w;
}
```

Comment: You might wanna ask this on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Also, don't forget to remove this question.

Comment: Compile it with tcc. It tends to produce very small executable files. The practicality of that undertaking is an entirely separate question though...

Comment: Use http://upx.sourceforge.net/

Comment: The large size is usually due to the `stdio` library being included in the executable. Some systems, such as UNIX, use shared libraries which results in smaller executables. You can trim the size somewhat by not including debug information and stripping the symbol table from the executable. The exact details depend on **which OS and compiler you are using**.

Comment: Use UPX if you want your program to be detected as a virus and to consume more system memory and start up more slowwly.